# How to do I get the form values in Springboot sent from angular?

Tags: spring-boot

I am building a formData

```
const formulario = new FormData();

formulario.append('preco', this.formularioCasaVenda.get('preco').value);
formulario.append('foto_1', this.formularioCasaVenda.get('foto_1').value);
formulario.append('dormitorios', this.formularioCasaVenda.get('dormitorios').value);
```

I am sending it in a post request.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
};
return this.http.post<Casa>("http://localhost:8080/api/casas-venda", formData1).pipe(
  tap((product: Casa) => console.log(`added product w/ id=$`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<Casa>('addProduct'))
);
```

How can I access dormitorios, foto_1, preco from the Spring boot controller, so I can populate a model?

My "desperate" atempt.

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@PostMapping("casas-venda")
public CasaVenda storeCasaVenda(@RequestParam("formulario") MultipartFile[] casaVenda){

      CasaVenda casaVendaDB = new CasaVenda();    
      casaVendaDB.setDormitorios(1);
      casaVendaDB.setPreco( Double.parseDouble(casaVenda[1].toString()));
      casaVendaDB.setPreco(900.00);


      return casaVendaDB;

   // return this.casaVendaRepositorio.save(casaVenda);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of solving it:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@PostMapping("/casas-venda")
public CasaVenda storeCasaVenda(@RequestParam("dormitorios") Integer dormitorios, 
           @RequestParam("preco") BigDecimal preco,
           @RequestParam("foto_1") MultipartFile foto) {

  CasaVenda casaVendaDB = new CasaVenda();    
  casaVendaDB.setDormitorios(dormitorios);
  casaVendaDB.setPreco(preco.doubleValue());

  // foto I am assuming is a file, so you receive it and you have to get the InputStream from it.

  return casaVendaDB;

  // return this.casaVendaRepositorio.save(casaVenda);
}
```

One hint:

> Don't return in the endpoints @Entity classes, it is not a nice practice, instead you should create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) and only return to the Frontend what they need to know.

https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html

I hope I could help you.